# Pass selected checkboxes to controller and perform insert operation

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a Visualforce page with a page block section which contains multiple rows from different object (Result from query in controller from custom object called "Location__c"). I need to pass the id's of selected rows to controller and perform insert operation to be stored in another custom object called "Desiredlocation__c" with the id's that i received, "Desireclocation__c" is parenting to custom object called "TLead__c". Can anyone help?
[image]

My VF

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="incDesiredLocationsController">
<apex:pageMessages />
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="New Desired Location">
    <div align="center">   
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
    </div>     
    <apex:pageblockSection title="Select Location" columns="1">      
            <apex:selectCheckboxes value="{!locationIds}" layout="PageDirection">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!locationSelect}"/>
            </apex:selectCheckboxes><br/>
    </apex:pageblockSection>         
      </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

My controller

public class incDesiredLocationsController {

```
//add multiple desired location

public List<SelectOption> getlocationSelect(){

List<SelectOption> locationSelect = new List<SelectOption>();
locationIds = new List<Id>();

List<Location__c> dloc = [SELECT City__c,Id, Region__c FROM Location__c where Country__c = 'ID' ORDER BY City__c asc];

for(Location__c loc:dloc)
    locationSelect.add(new SelectOption(loc.Id, loc.City__c));  

return locationSelect;

}

String[] locationIds = new String[]{};
public String[] getlocationIds () {
    return locationIds;
}

public void setlocationIds(String[] locationIds) {
    this.locationIds = locationIds;
}

public PageReference save(){
         //code block here
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `desiredLocationList` and implement below method:

**--edited--**

```
public List<SelectOption> getlocationSelect(){

    List<SelectOption> locationSelect = new List<SelectOption>();

    List<Location__c> dloc = [SELECT City__c,Id Region__c FROM Location__c where Country__c = 'ID' ORDER BY City__c asc];

    for(Location__c loc:dloc)
        locationSelect.add(new SelectOption(loc.City__c, loc.City__c));  

    return locationSelect;
}
```

and remove `public List<SelectOption> locationSelect {get; set;}`.

Now, implement below getter and setter:

```
String[] locationIds = new String[]{};
public String[] getlocationIds () {
    return locationIds;
}

public void setlocationIds(String[] locationIds) {
    this.locationIds = locationIds;
}
```

and remove `public List<Id> locationIds{get; set;}`. Above setter (`set` method) will automatically get the selected location ids.

Now,

```
public PageReference save(){
    System.debug('locationIds => '+locationIds);
    /*
    if(tleadName == null || tleadName == ''){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'T Lead is Required!'));
    }else{
        Location__c loc1 = new Location__c();
        loc1.Name = tleadName1;
        loc1.Id = tleadId1;
        insert loc1;
    }*/
    return null;
}
```

Here `System.debug('locationIds => '+locationIds);` will print the selected location ids in log. You can process `locationIds` further.

Comment: Hi, salesforcesas I got error when saving the class Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: locationIds at line 54 column 5 , could you help me with this? and also would be very helpful if you can give reference or hint on how to perform the insert operation once the ID's are retrieved in the controller, should I perform for loop to iterate each ID then do something?

Comment: can you update code in question

Comment: I have updated the code with your suggestions included, I also edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: added return type for `getlocationSelect` method and also declared `String[] locationIds = new String[]{};`. Please do changes in both places

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand on your last comments, `getlocationSelect` has return type `return locationSelect;` ?

Comment: `public List<SelectOption> getlocationSelect()` => here `List<SelectOption>` is return data type. Earlier it was void.

Comment: Ok salesforcesas, but then it will throw error in VisualForce since the initial action I set was void data type not return type, how do I handle this in my VF? it was `<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="incDesiredLocationsController" action="{!desiredLocationList}">`

Comment: remove `action="{!desiredLocationList}"` in apex:page. Select options need a getter, or else it behaves very wierdly. Some times it does not work properly without getter.

Comment: Hi salesforcesas, I have simplified the controller ,  Im able to show "Location__c" record as checkbox in VF and its selectable. one last question I think, how do I prepopulate `<apex:inputText label="T Lead" style="float:left;">` with record that is in context & perform insert operation here based on selected list `public PageReference save(){
         //code block here
}` . Thank you very much for your help sir!!!